# How to put co-first author, institution address and corresponding together?

Tags: tables, author-number, paper

I am currently writing a paper, author 1 and author 2 are co-first authors, and author 2 is the corresponding author. How to write this in Latex. Below is one example from word

[image]

Comment: Some journals have custom document classes which handle this,  My favorite approach puts the author info into a tabular.

Comment: Can you refer to this question?
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649662/how-to-put-envelop-for-corresponding-author-at-the-bottom