# How to put 'envelop' for corresponding author at the bottom?

Tags: tables, templates, documentclass-writing, author, paper

I am writing a paper, James and Henry are both co-first authors, and Henry is the corresponding author. Below is the code.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{elsarticle}
%

\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{comment}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman clone text and math font

% for color models
\usepackage{xcolor}

% for nice coloring in tables
\usepackage{nicematrix}

% for multi-row cells
\usepackage{multirow}

%for Helvetica-like sans font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{marvosym}



\begin{document}
%

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{xxxx}

\cortext[coauthor]{Both authors contributed equally}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\affiliation[inst1]{organization={United Kingdom}}


\author[inst1]{James\corref{coauthor}}
\author[inst1]{Henry\corref{coauthor}\textsuperscript{\Letter}}
\affiliation[inst2]{organization={United States}}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

We can see that Henry is the corresponding author, and an envelop is after his name. How do I put this envelop mark at the bottom of the paper like the '*' at the red marked place below? After the envelop, it will write:'corresponding author: email address.'

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fix this.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{elsarticle}
%

\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{comment}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman clone text and math font

% for color models
\usepackage{xcolor}

% for nice coloring in tables
\usepackage{nicematrix}

% for multi-row cells
\usepackage{multirow}

%for Helvetica-like sans font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{marvosym}



\begin{document}
%

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{xxxx}

\cortext[coauthor]{Both authors contributed equally}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\affiliation[inst1]{organization={United Kingdom}}


\author[inst1]{James\corref{coauthor}}
\author[inst1]{Henry\corref{coauthor}\textsuperscript{\Letter}}
\affiliation[inst2]{organization={United States}}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\blank}  \footnote{{\Letter} {Corresponding author, Email address: \linkable{}}}
\end{document}
```